# Point-normal equation of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for the way to find the point-normal equation of a plane given three points. I can't find the method anywhere including in my notes so any tips would be appreciated. I realize you might want to explain with a specific example so one of the problems I am trying to solve involves plane containing the points: $$p = \left( \matrix{
  2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \hfill \cr 
  4 \hfill \cr}  \right),q = \left( \matrix{
  4 \hfill \cr 
  4 \hfill \cr 
  2 \hfill \cr}  \right),r = \left( \matrix{
   - 2 \hfill \cr 
  0 \hfill \cr 
  2 \hfill \cr}  \right)$$

I also wonder how I can prove a certain point is/isn't contained in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a point so you only need a normal. Construct two independent vectors parallel to the plane by taking differences between your points. Then the product of those vectors is orthogonal to the plane.

An arbitrary point with given coordinates belongs to the plane if its difference with the base point is orthogonal to that normal vector.

Comment: So for instance I could find (p-q) x (q-r) and that is the normal?

Comment: That's right. And if that cross product turns out to be zero, it means that the three points are all on one line, so they don't determine a unique plane!